# javascript returning an object but not what I expected to see

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is returning an object and not what I expected to see. When I output the output in console, I get object but all the data is there. What is supposed to happen, is that the id is passed to actionrow and this does the ajax call to the db. The object is being output from console.log(datarow); in the code.

I am using [jqxWidgets](http://www.jqwidgets.com) for grid and data

```
// action row.
$("#actionrowbutton").bind('click', function () {
    var selectedrowindex = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('getselectedrowindex');
    var datarow = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('getrowdata', selectedrowindex);
    var rowscount = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('getdatainformation').rowscount;

    if (selectedrowindex >= 0 && selectedrowindex < rowscount) {
        var rows = $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('getrows', selectedrowindex);
        var id = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('getrowid', selectedrowindex);
        //var service = datarow;
        console.log(datarow);

        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('actionrow', id);

        //Open action dialog window
        $( "#actionWindow" ).dialog({
          //title: 'action error',
          resizable: false,
          modal: true,
          position: ['center', 'center'],
          buttons: {
             "Ok": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");

                $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('refreshdata');
              },
              Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );

                //$('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('refreshdata');
              }
         }
       });
    }
});

actionrow: function (actrowid) {
    // synchronize with the server - send action command
    var data = "action=true&id=" + actrowid;
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'data.php',
        data: data,
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
            // action command is executed.
        }
    });                         
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at your code, I am left with a question.
What is "actionrow", is it a function or a method of jqxgrid object?  If it isn't it should be written like so:

```
function actionrow(actrowid) {
    // synchronize with the server - send action command
    var data = "action=true&id=" + actrowid;
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'data.php',
        data: data,
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        // action command is executed.
        }
    });                         
}
```

And called like so in your if statement.

```
actionrow(id); //not $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('actionrow', id);
```

Comment: Damian, sorry I have only been doing js for a short while and your answer althought I am sure correct, leaves me out of my depth. How would I adapt your code to mine. Thanks

Comment: @user1532468 - No I'm sorry I should of read your post more clearly, din't see that you are using a widget so what I put is wrong. Let me take a look again and edit.

Comment: Damian. actionrow contains the call too ajax. The line is jqxGrid parameter for taking say in this case, the id to pass to ajax. However, nothing is going through to data.php. Nothing is coming back through firebug nor any nor any echo commands etc. Thanks